# How pass header value in properties file sql query in camel

Tags: apache-camel

Hi I have problem in reading header value in select query.

In Camel route

```
.setHeader("today", simple("${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}"))
.to("sql:{{sql.selectquery}}")
```

In sql.properties file

```
sql.selectquery=SELECT * FROM Table  where to_char(datetime,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') <= :#today
```

Please help me how to get header value or pass header value in query written properties file

Comment: And what problem do you encounter? An Exception? A wrong query result?

Comment: What if you use simple expression in place of the sql parameter like `sql.selectquery=SELECT * FROM Table  where to_char(datetime,'YYYYMMDDHH24MISS') <= :#${date:now:yyyyMMddHHmmss}` ?

Answer (score 0):

Just a wild guess (because you don't mention the problem symptom). The `to` statement is for static endpoint URIs, but yours is dynamic.

Try to use `toD` statement for dynamic endpoints:

```
.toD("sql:{{sql.selectquery}}")
```

Comment: I want to pass header value in properties file ,  in sql.properties file i have query "select * from table where date = "currentDate" " .Instead of current date I want header value.